# Cannot be accessed with an instance reference issue with Points and size

Tags: c#

What I am doing wrong here?

I am getting this error whether I try to add a point in the last line, I looked around in stackoverflow but still I am not able to see what is wrong here!

```
      Point points;
    public static Size Size1;

    public  void loadData()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("IndianOcean.XML");


        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            Point p = new Point();

            Size Size1 = new Size();
            Size1.Height = 10;
            Size1.Width = 10;
            //Convert Latitude into degrees
            String Lat = dr[0].ToString();
            double LatSec = Double.Parse(Lat.Substring(4, 4)) / 6000;
            double LatMin = (Double.Parse(Lat.Substring(2, 2)) + LatSec) / 60;
            //p.X = Double.Parse(Lat.Substring(0, 2)) + LatMin;
            string a = Lat.Substring(0, 2);
            double a1 = (double)Convert.ToDouble(a);
            p.X = (int) a1;

            //Convert Longitude into degrees
            String Long = dr[1].ToString();
            double LongSec = Double.Parse(Long.Substring(5, 4)) / 6000;
            double LongMin = (Double.Parse(Long.Substring(3, 2)) + LongSec) / 60;
            p.Y =(int)(Convert.ToDouble(Long.Substring(0, 3)) + LongMin);
            //points.Offset(p.X, p.Y);

            points.Add(p,Size1);
        }
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: Should be : points.Add(p); You need to change the size of the point which is not done in the Add() method.

Comment: Was `points` meant to be some form of collection rather than a single `Point`? Also, not sure why `Size1` has been declared outside the method (and `static`, to boot). Maybe edit your question and explain *what you're trying to do*, rather than expect us to deduce it from the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Add` is as static method of `Point`. That means this method can only be accessed in a static way

```
Point result = Point.Add(p,Size1); //adds Size to Point and returns a new Point
```

The the outcome of the operation is reflected in the return value. `p` will be unchanged

Comment: This solved it.